# equivalent data type of set in mysql to java

Tags: java, mysql

Actually I want to store a type in java whose value can be combination of multiple single values with comma (,) separated. In mysql there is a type called set() used for similar functionality.

For eg, say

```
3 A,B,C
```

result can be combination of these 3 with comma seperated

In mysql with type set() type will be like

```
set('A','B','C')
```

and values for that field can be combination of these 3 with comma seperated for 2 or more values. ie 1 field value can be

```
A,B similarly B,C
but A,D will throw SqlException
```

Im looking for such a functionality in java

Comment: but there is a type called set() in mysql. It is showing in mysql workbench Im using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get Set data type from mysql to java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897735/how-to-get-set-data-type-from-mysql-to-java)

Comment: The [doc of mysql 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) about Set

Comment: oops mix up on my part. Working with different RDBMS sucks

Comment: @AxelH actually my question is not how to retreive it from database, but is there any scope in java to have a type which uses same functionality that of set() in mysql

Comment: Well, you have enums and collection to do something close to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enum` to build the set of value

```
public enum MySet{
    A, B, C
}
```

Or constants (which is the same basicly)

Then, you use any collection to store those value like :

```
MySet[] values = {MySet.A, MySet.B};
```

This could be shorted using some static import of the enum

```
import static MySet.*;

public class Main{

   MySet[] values = {A, B};

}
```